# Prevent loss of highlight when clicking on other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a blog where I want a section to add a post. I'm imagining it very similar to the StackExchange editor I'm using right now to write this post.

I've managed to work with the textarea to get things like current caret position, insert at position, etc.

The problem I'm running into now is **not losing the highlighted text in the textarea when the user clicks on another element, ie: the bold tool**.

By default (at least in Chrome) when you highlight text in a textarea and then click elsewhere on the page, the textarea loses focus and the highlighted text with it.

Comment: Can you please provide markup and js?

Comment: @jeekonline I'm aware of the rules but I don't feel it's pertinent here. You can imagine my markup is <textarea></textarea> and I'm asking how not to loose focus when I click outside that element. The answer can be anything js/jquery.... My markup is actually quite heavy and I feel posting it will just dilute the focus of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the textarea loses focus it will by default lose any previous selection, so at the onblur event you can save the current selection using the following function:

```
    function getSelectedText() {
        var txtarea = document.getElementById(textBoxScript);
        var start = txtarea.selectionStart;
        var finish = txtarea.selectionEnd;
        var sel = txtarea.value.substring(start, finish);
        return sel;
    }
```

And to set it back on focus event you can use the following function:

```
    function selectText(startPos, endPos, tarea) {
        // Chrome / Firefox
        if (typeof (tarea.selectionStart) != "undefined") {
            tarea.focus();
            tarea.selectionStart = startPos;
            tarea.selectionEnd = endPos;
            return true;
        }
        // IE
       if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
            tarea.focus();
            tarea.select();
            var range = document.selection.createRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd("character", endPos);
            range.moveStart("character", startPos);
            range.select();
            return true;
       }
    }
```